# Cannot Connect to SQL Server using tedious Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssms, tedious

So my school has an SQL Server "SQL.SCHOOL.EDU\STUDENTSQLSERVER,4500" and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to connect to it using tedious. 
I have an express back end that is using react for the front end side of things. However I am currently only working on the express index.js to try and get some sort of feedback from the Server and eventually the data base.

Here is my index.js file in its entirity

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES; 


/* DBConfig */
var config = {
  server: 'SQL.SCHOOL.EDU',
  userName: 'user1',
  password: 'password1',
  debug: true,
  connectionTimeout: 300000,
  requestTimeout: 300000,
  options: {
    database: 'user1',
    instanceName: 'STUDENTSQLSERVER', 
  },
  port: 4500,
};
/*Get users from DB */
function getUsers() {
  var connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err)
    }
    // If no error, then good to go...
    request = new Request("select * from 'Users'", function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }});
    var result ="";
    request.on('row', function(columns) {
      columns.forEach(function(column) {
        if (column.value === null) {  
          console.log('NULL');  
        } else {  
          result+= column.value + " ";  
        }
      });
      console.log(result);
    });

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {  
      console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');  
      });

    connection.execSql(request);
  });


}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/Users', (req, res) => {
  getUsers();
  const users = [

    {id:1, userName: "Lee", age: 23, email: "Lee@email.com"},
    {id:2, userName:  "Bob", age: 22, email: "Bobo@email.com"},
    {id:3, userName:  "James", age: 32, email: "james@email.com"},
    {id:2, userName:  "Lauren", age: 26, email: "lren@email.com"},
    {id:2, userName:  "t-dawg", age: 20, email: "dogg@email.com"},
  ]
  res.json(users)
});




module.exports = router;
```

The connection continues to time out but I have and my classmates have been able to connect using .net, and php.

If anyone can help me that would be great, I have tried to include the entire server name within the "server:" and placed the port within the "port:" but to no avail

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an npm package called mssql (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) I would recommend using that like this. Create a separate .json file for your config like this:

config.json

```
{
 "mssql": {
   "server": 'SQL.SCHOOL.EDU',
   "userName": 'user1',
   "password": 'password1',
   "database": 'user1',
   "debug": true,
   "connectionTimeout": 300000,
   "requestTimeout": 300000,
   "options": {
    "instanceName": 'STUDENTSQLSERVER', 
   },
  "port": 4500
 }
```

Then your index.js can use that like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express').Router();
const sql = require('mssql');
const sql_config = require(path.join("..", "config", "config.json")).mssql;
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(sql_config);
pool.connect(err => { if (err) throw err });

function getUsers() {
 let get_request = new sql.Request(pool);
 get_request.query(`select * from table1`, (err,result) => {
  if(err) {
   *handle error*
  }
  *do stuff with result here*
  })
}
```

Comment: the connection is not successful, the error just stopped. I tried to use pool.close after I call getUsers(); and the error "Cannot close a pool while it is connecting" Without the "pool.close()" im getting the error "code: 'ECONNCLOSED',
  name: 'ConnectionError'"

Comment: You could make getUsers() into a promise then call pool.close after it resolves some data, but I would take a closer look at your config because I think the problem is in that object

Comment: Ok, well I was able to use your example to get me close. MSSQl uses "user" and I was frustrated with the schools sql server so I spun up my own using aws RDS free tier and was able to connect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another quick question, I don't know how much experience you have at a production level but, do you think it would be more cost effective to use a connect function containing the var pool and pool.connect in order to only establish a connection when needed?

Comment: It really depends on how many connections you will be needing. I have gone that route where I create a connection function where I know I am only going to be needing a single connection. Pooling can be great because it can lower the need for multiple connections to a single database for multiple calls. If you are going to use this route, I recommend reading up on the documention here https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#pool-management